# Path problems during installation of QSTK

Tags: shell, ubuntu, path, installation, qstk

I am trying to install QSTK. I have changed the installation directory from the default home directory to another one. I have made the changes for two variables $QS and $QSDATA in my config.sh. Further following the instruction I copied the config.sh to local.sh. 
Then going ahead I edited the ~/.profile AND ~/.bashrc and added the line in the end

```
source ~/path/to/install/directory/QSTK/local.sh
```

Then I logged out and logged in. And I got this as message on my terminal:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

But when I echo $QS and $QSDATA they show the correct path.

Then when I try to run any example from my QSTK/Examples it says module not found although its very much there in the folder. 
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `~/path/to/install/directory/QSTK/local.sh` to be the actual directory that you have it installed in.  For my installation, I changed it to `source ~/QSTK/local.sh` because I installed QSTK to the root of my home directory.